# Using mutual recursion

Tags: recursion, ocaml

I want to execute this code, but I have this error. Is there mutual recursion in OCaml ?

> Error: Unbound value quicksort Did you mean tquicksort?

My problem:

```
let rec tquicksort lm l lM = 
    match l with
        | [] -> unirL(unir (rev lm) lM)
        | lx::lxs -> let (la, lb) = part lx lxs in
                    if nroelem la < nroelem lb then 
                        tquicksort (quicksort (la::lm)) lb lM
                    else 
                        tquicksort lm la (quicksort (lb::lM));;
let quicksort l = tquicksort [] l [];;
```

Comment: What are you calling a prototype?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "don't work"?

Comment: Sorry, I don't write in english well. When I execute it, the error:
"Error: Unbound value quicksort
Did you mean tquicksort?"

Comment: Aha, I get it. I'll fix up my answer.

Comment: @JeffreyScofield The second function is not recursive. How Can I do ?

Comment: After fixing the mutual recursion you now have a type error. It's hard to say where because you don't give all the code. Perhaps you should open a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking for a forward declaration to allow mutual recursion. The way to make this work in OCaml is with `let rec ... and ...`.

For example:

```
 let rec g x = if x < 2 then x else f x
 and f x = g (x - 1)
```

Comment: I wrote:
let rec tquicksort lm l lM = .......
and quicksort l = tquicksort [] l [];;
But it displayed the error: "This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type 'a list list. The type variable 'a occurs inside 'a list.

Comment: My OCaml is 4.01.